# Android: Is this method always available and present?

Tags: android, performance, storage, android-file

I want to make the most out root access to all folders.
this order is correct and always available and present?

```
File ffile = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getParent());
// return "/"
// "/" out root access to all folders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call getRootDirectory() to get the system directory.  If you want the true root of all folders, it's always just "/".  So just do `new File("/");`

Comment: `new File("/");` good work now :) . this method `new File("/");` always available and present in all API android?

Comment: Yes.  That constructor for a file is part of the Java spec, it dates back to the 1990s.